# I am trying to create a html file to extract and download videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I've been trying to use `fetch` and `axios`, but it does not seem to work. I don't know how to resolve this problem and it seems that it is the wrong aproach, but I am not certain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video Downloader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Downloader</h1>
    <p>Enter the URL of the video you want to download:</p>
    <input type="text" id="video-url" placeholder="Video URL">
    <button onclick="downloadVideo()">Download</button>
    <div id="error-message"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg"></script>
    <script>
      async function downloadVideo() {
        const videoUrl = document.getElementById('video-url').value;

        try {
          const response = await fetch(videoUrl);
          const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type');
          const extension = contentType.split('/')[1];
          const blob = await response.blob();

          let videoBlob;
          if (extension === 'mp4') {
            videoBlob = blob;
          } else {
            const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });
            await ffmpeg.load();
            ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'video', await fetchFile(blob));
            await ffmpeg.run('-i', 'video', '-c', 'copy', '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov', 'video.mp4');
            videoBlob = await fetchFile(ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'video.mp4'));
          }

          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = url;
          a.download = 'video.mp4';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
        } catch (error) {
          const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
          errorMessage.textContent = `Error downloading video: ${error}`;
        }
      }

      async function fetchFile(file) {
        const response = await fetch(file);
        return new Uint8Array(await response.arrayBuffer());
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I using the wrong aproach?

Comment: You might want to add a sample video link that you have use to try the download.

Comment: "does not work" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, like a mechanic can't fix a car that "does not work" without any other information about the problem. How isn't it working? What [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you done? What exactly happens when you run this? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc.See also [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: As you're new to Stackoverflow, you should also read the [tour], the [ask] guide, and how to make a [mre] of your issue (including relevant code and specific information about errors and/or unexpected results) - don't assume that we can, or will, run your code and try to figure it out from the beginning (and even if we do that, there might be differences in the runtime environments which mean that we don't get the same results).